# How to run an multilevelanalysis for H0: x = 0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multilevel-analysis

I have nested data within schoolclasses, therefore I want to run multilevel analysis' with R, package lme4. 
My hypothesis is H0: x = 0. 
I don't know how do put this into a multilevel analysis. Can you help me with this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify what your variables are. What is your dependent variable, and what is the independent variable? What is the null hypothesis? What is this x variable that is 0 in your null hypothesis?

With that said, if you have a continuous dependent variable (y) and some independent variables (x1, x1, x3) and schoolclass you can do the analysis like this:

```
lmer (y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|schoolclass))
```

But if you have a variable on schools and another variable on class, where class is nested in schools (so that each unique class has a unique name/number in your data) you can try this:

```
lmer (y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|school) + (1|class))
```

This is a three-way hierarchical model that may or may not be more appropriate.

But as I said, we need to know more about your variables. The code above only works if your dependent variable is continuous.